# Problem installing ndless-sdk: error building genzehn

Tags: windows, cygwin, ti-nspire

I am trying to install Ndless sdk on my Windows computer (with CygWin). I run

```
.../Ndless/ndless-sdk/toolchain/build_toolchain.sh
```

and I fixed all the problems with that. After that, according to the [instructions](https://github.com/ndless-nspire/Ndless/wiki/Ndless-SDK:-C-and-assembly-development-introduction#Cygwin), I went in the (top) Ndless directory and ran "make". It got stuck at this point and whatever I did, I could not get it to compile "genzehn"

```
.../Ndless/ndless-sdk/tools/genzehn/genzehn.cpp
```

What should I do?

The log(both stdout and stderr for make in "Ndless"):
https://pastebin.com/fpH6Mf2v

```
make all in genzehn...
make[3]: Entering directory '/Ndless/ndless-sdk/tools/genzehn'
g++ -Wall -Wextra -std=c++11 -I elfio-3.2 genzehn.cpp -lboost_program_options -lz -o ../../bin/genzehn || g++ -Wall -Wextra -std=c++11 -I elfio-3.2 genzehn.cpp -lboost_program_options-mt -lz -o ../../bin/genzehn
In file included from genzehn.cpp:12:
zehn.h:1:1: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘.’ token
    1 | ../../include/zehn.h
      | ^
genzehn.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
genzehn.cpp:96:9: error: ‘Zehn_header’ was not declared in this scope; did you mean ‘gz_header’?
   96 |         Zehn_header header;
      |         ^~~~~~~~~~~
      |         gz_header
```

Comment: look on `include/zehn.h` for hint on the problem. Is the source using `Cmake` or `Automake` for setting the makefiles ?

Comment: Well, there seems to be nothing wrong with zehn.h.
Also, what do you mean?

Comment: If `zehn.h` starts with `../../include/zehn.h`  I see a problem.

Comment: Ah, it does.
Should I put inside of it the actual content of the file?

Comment: Because I opened it and I saw this path, and I assumed you meant I should check that file.

Comment: Write this as an answer so that I can mark it as correct.